# How to prevent Mouse Without Borders security key expiration?

Tags: kvm-switch

[Mouse Without Borders](http://www.aka.ms/mm) (a.k.a., "MWB") v2.2.1.0327 is an indispensable free virtual KVM released by the [Microsoft Garage](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/workbench/) which I've used for years on different versions of Windows, but as of late on Windows 10 it often fails with, "The security key has expired, please generate a new key." Clicking OK makes the error go away, and then Apply makes it work again--but the error keeps reappearing intermittently and making the software cease to function all over again. Any idea on a root cause and how I could resolve this once and for all?

UPDATE:
One year later and I am still unsure of how to prevent this from happening, as I don't want the key to expire at all! I am now on Windows 11 and the problem persists.

[image]

Comment: you might ask the author>>>>https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/mouse-without-borders-setupuser-guide-tips-tricks/0523308d-3406-4273-b86e-bef28aa6b50d

Comment: I did. Thank you! I'm waiting for an answer wherever it comes first https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/mouse-without-borders-setupuser-guide-tips-tricks/0523308d-3406-4273-b86e-bef28aa6b50d?rtAction=1672715849830&page=141

Comment: An answer from Microsoft hasn't come yet and I have little faith it will soon. One interesting tidbit of information is that if I enable the Administrator user on Windows 10, then MWB does work on the Windows login screen. As soon as I login with my personal account (not Administrator), I lose MWB and I get the key expiration issue.

Answer (score -2):

Here the solution:

- Open "Mouse without Borders" settings
- Go to tab "Machine Setup" and renew or modify your "Security Key".
- Use the Button "New Key" (because the security key must be auto generated in one of the machines").
- Change / set this Security Key on all your clients.